# What are the Copenhagen Card conditions?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, denmark, copenhagen

I am failing at finding the specific conditions of the *Copenhagen Card* that allows you to travel through the city for (in my case) 120 hours, since I am going for 5 days.

I have seen that it starts counting the moment you activate it, but I would like to know if it counts on a per day basis or strictly 120 hours.

Example: I activate at 10pm on saturday. If it only counts days, I'd have Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Thursday and Wednesday.

If it only takes into account hours, I'd have until 10pm of the next Tuesday.

The second case is the one that I want since I leave late, but inside the 120 hours stablished.

Could someone help me with this? I only find blogs explaining it but I am not sure if it has an official page that I haven't found or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The card is explicitly valid for **"120 hours"**, not "5 days". It has a blank field where you must fill in the exact starting time -- not just the date -- before you start using the card.

That is what the official [prices and conditions](http://www.copenhagencard.com/prices-and-conditions) page says.